# Set variable based on ribbon drop-down

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ribbon

I created customized ribbon, with a drop down, XML:

```
<dropDown id="sections" onAction="sectionsmacro" >
<item id="section1" image="section1" label="navy" />
<item id="section2" image="section2" label="sapphire" />
<item id="section3" image="section3" label="purple" />
<item id="section4" image="section4" label="emerald" /> 
<item id="section5" image="section5" label="cyan" />
</dropDown>
```

I would like to set a macro, which will be working on "if then" cases, dependently what is selected on a drop-down.

So, I have a macro which color everything in black, but if purple is chosen, my macro makes everything in purple. How can I make a reference to the ribbon drop-down on a macro level? thanks for your help!

---

Thanks, although it is not exactly what I meant... Let's say I have chosen 'navy' on my drop-down and that is all. It has index 0. The next step is to use that variable in the other macro. So I would have something like this:

```
Sub tablecolour()

'if value on drop down = 0 ('navy') then 
else end if

end sub
```

So based on the value chosen on the drop-down I would like to run another macro in a certain way. I don't know how to use to value from drop-down to be read as variable in a separate macro.

Comment: If you are okay with hard-coding the choices in the ribbon dropdown control, you can always used the passed index argument of the callback to get the index of the selection. So in your case - index=0 means they have selected navy, ect.

Comment: You need to save the selected value in a callback similar to the `sectionsmacro` callback in @jkpieterse s example and then use the saved value in `tablecolour`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Add this to a module in your Excel file:

```
'Callback for sections onAction
Sub sectionsmacro(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
    MsgBox index
End Sub
```

As you'll notice you'll get the index of the item which was selected (starting at zero)